# Api gateway integration with s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I'm trying to build a rest api on AWS, using API Gateway.
My wish is that using the API Gateway integration with S3, I can upload files to the bucket in users' directories.

In the first steps, I managed to create the API that uploads to the s3 bucket, with the cognito authorizer. But I can't get it to only upload prefixes with the user's name, for example.

Is there any way this can be done?

Upload a file into a user prefix exclusive bucket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a good idea to upload files to S3 using Amazon API Gateway directly. Amazon API Gateway has a payload size limit of `10 MB`. A better approach would be to generate an [S3 PreSigned URL](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/generate-presigned-url-modular-aws-sdk-javascript/) using a Lambda function and then send that URL to the frontend to upload the file. When creating the PreSigned URL, you are free to name S3 object key what